# Total score in question list and tooltip

Tags: bug, tag-score

[image]

Total score of question displayed in question list and Total score of question getting displayed in tooltip of tags are not same. Is this a bug?

Comment: Caching. Tag scores are recalculated infrequently (once a day, when that process works which has been erratic sometimes).

Comment: http://shouldiblamecaching.com

Comment: Related: [When is tag score calculated?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/269040/62576)