# When is tag score calculated?

Tags: support, tag-score

If I answer ten questions that are upvoted in say the jQuery tag, my tag score doesn't update automatically.

For instance, yesterday I was awarded the bronze tag for MySQL, recently the jQuery tag also, but these awards seem to have been calculated on a day that I wasn't active - which leads me to assume that they are queued for re-calculation somehow.

How regularly is this performed?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Tag scores and tag badges are all updated by a process that runs daily at 03:00 UTC.

Note, however, that the process [has a history of failing on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/226681/tag-scores-are-not-updated-and-the-issue-is-getting-worse) - so they may not actually get updated every day.

Comment: Seems like, now it's being updated during the day as well, isn't it?

Comment: Can you confirm that? They're still at 03:00 UTC? Or real-time?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like now, the tag scores are getting updated in real-time.