# Vote count not incrementing for Electorate badge

Tags: discussion, bug, electorate-badge

I am looking forward to getting the Electorate badge and I am very close right now.

In order to progress further, I voted on few questions that deserved it (vote ups). I also went through the review section and started casting my votes there.

However, my score doesnt go up! It is still stuck at where it was earlier.

What am I doing wrong here? **Is it a bug?**

**EDIT:**  I have waited until `03:00 UTC` as mentioned in [When is tag score calculated?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/269043/586051) , but I dont see any update. I had casted few votes yesterday and the day before yesterday too.

Comment: Did you wait a day or so so the stats could be refreshed?

Comment: @PatrickHofman Yes, I did.

Comment: How long did you wait? Some processes aren't that reliable. There have been issues with tag badges for example.

Comment: @PatrickHofman It has been 2 days.

Comment: so... you'd want to know ***how*** exactly are the votes counted? the formulæ even?

Comment: @CSᵠ I did not mean that at all. I just wanted to point out the buggy behaviour of it.

Comment: The link you provided in your link also shows [this post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/226681/tag-scores-are-not-updated-and-the-issue-is-getting-worse) which shows how irregular it is. The time interval could even be a week

Comment: Ok, it has updated the score now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I see that it is updating regularly now. What happened previously was like a glitch and there was a delay of about 2-3 days.

I would advice the future readers with this problem to wait for few days as it can take upto a week for the score to be updated.

[Related.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/226681/tag-scores-are-not-updated-and-the-issue-is-getting-worse)