# Do you lose a gold tag badge if questions are retagged?

Tags: discussion, support, badges, tag-badges

I've been going through some of the highly voted [iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/iphone) questions and retagging them where appropriate. (Unfortunately, only about 5%, if not fewer, are using the tag correctly!)

I realised as I was going through, that some people with the gold badge for [iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/iphone) might have their tag scores significantly lowered, enough to push them under 1000 again.

Do these users lose the badge and the associated dupe hammer? Or once the badge is awarded does it stick?

I realised I could just wait a while and check if one of the would-be affected users is affected, but I don't know how often the caches are updated.

Comment: Users do lose tag badges if they no longer meet the criteria for them. They would lose the dupe hammer if they lost the gold badge.

Comment: Ah! Then I may have stripped some users of their badges, but hopefully I will have replaced it with an iOS badge in some cases.

Comment: @JamesWebster It hardly matters because the tag script hasn't run for at least three days

Comment: How do you know when the script is run?

Comment: The scores change. If you're aware of your score and that you've got votes in the last few days you might notice that your score has not changed.

Comment: @JamesWebster I've been over 1000 points in java for three days but I haven't gotten my badge yet :-/ (and it hasn't even changed). See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/269043/1768232

Comment: Not quite the same, but it feel like so: I've earned a gold medal in baseball during the Olympics, baseball is voted away as an olympic sport. Please return your gold medal since you are not entitled to it anymore. The users has been able to achieve something, it isn't quite fair to revoke it afterwards.

Comment: @Mouser. It's more like "You got a gold medal in Olympic basketball, but you were actually playing volleyball and there was a clerical error. We take your basketball medal from you, then work out if you're actually eligible for a volleyball one"

Comment: So if JavaScript tag gets deleted all the badges will be revoked. That's kind of harsh.

Comment: @Mouser, Why? If there is no concept of (e.g.) Javascript anymore, what is the point of a badge for a topic that "doesn't exist"

Comment: However, this question isn't about the deletion of badges, rather the retagging of questions. I'm removing "basketball" tags from "volleyball" questions and adding "volleyball" because those users are unfairly being credited as being good at "basketball" and are then rightfully credited as being good at "volleyball"

Comment: I'm a history teacher. So it's like you are saying that that history didn't exist. Sure we had a JavaScript tag and there were people great with it. So great they earned badges. Badges give a user more credibility. Obama's Nobel peace price isn't revoked when he goes to war.

Comment: @JamesWebster, you're right about the retagging. However same principal is applied at deletion.

Comment: But Obama's prize *would* be revoked if he were accidentally awarded the Chemistry prize. Then we would rightfully give him the Peace Prize.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Yes, they'll lose their badge if they no longer meet the qualifications.

Tag badges are directly contingent on you reaching and *maintaining* your score in the tag.

From the [central *tag badges* FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63835/what-are-tag-badges-how-do-they-work/63836#63836):

> #### My tag badge can't be revoked, like normal badges, right?
>
> Wrong. Tag badges, unlike normal badges, are automatically revoked upon a tag score recalculation if the tag is no longer eligible to have badges, or you no longer have the required tag score or minimum valid answer count for the badge.

The dupe hammer is contingent on the user having a gold badge. No gold tag badge, no hammer.

Comment: So what OP and alike should do? It seems to me obvious to still retag nevertheless but I think some directions from a mod himself would worth more than my humble opinion.

Comment: What's more important? The site quality (corectnees of questions, answers, categories, etc.) or just a yellow label on a profile? :) I prefer see someone (or myself) loose a gold badge instead of keeping a mistagged question.

Comment: Is the reverse true? Can you gain a badge based on retagging?

Comment: @StevenPenny: yes. Retagging changes the counts per tag per user, so on the next tag score recalculation you could gain a badge for posts that previously did not have that tag.

Comment: @JeromeJ, my question wasn't whether or not I should retag the questions. If the tags are wrong, I believe I should change them. I was just curious of the outcome.

Comment: @JeromeJ: the question asked was about what would happen *if* questions were retagged, not if it is a good idea to retag. I'd not worry about badges, and instead worry about the right tagging.

Comment: I'm sorry, this answer is wrong from what I can tell (*based on the actual question that was asked*). Retagging questions does not affect badges - only the original tags count. The FAQ refers to deleted questions (or deleted users) where rep points can be lost. Retagging does not do this.

Comment: @JonathanPotter: I think you are confusing closing a post with the dupehammer (where only original tags count) with tag badges. Tag badges are contingent on the *current* tags on a post.

Comment: @JonathanPotter: I have, in the past, lost tag badges because posts were retagged, as well as *gained* tag badges merely by adding a tag to a post where my answer score pushed me across the threshold.

Comment: The "dupehammer" is simply a gold tag badge as far as I know, they are one and the same. And if retagging really works then surely anyone who has got 1000 upvotes could just retag all the questions they have answered to gain any gold badge they want?

Comment: @JonathanPotter: yes, you could go around and retag questions on posts you answered. But if you ever found a user doing just that, just flag one of those posts for moderator attention and we'll investigate. Retagging a series of posts with an irrelevant tag never evades attention for long, anyway.

Comment: So original tags are relevant only when weilding the hammer but not for possessing it?

Comment: @JonathanPotter: exactly. We are talking about the rules governing tag badges here, not the rules of closing a question as a duplicate. That you get a hammer based on a tag badge is irrelevant here.

Comment: @JonathanPotter, you're confusing owning and using. Only users with a gold badge own a hammer. It can only be used on questions where the original tags *on that question* match the tag on the hammer