# Is [ipod-touch] synonymous with [iphone]?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonym-process

During my [recent mini-campaign](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/301017/do-you-lose-a-gold-tag-badge-if-questions-are-retagged) to fix some of the badly tagged [iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/iphone) questions, I've read the tag wiki several times and one bit keeps catching my eye.

> DO NOT use this tag unless you are addressing Apple's iPhone and/or **iPod  touch*** specifically.

<sup>*emphasis mine</sup>

Should the [ipod-touch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ipod-touch) and similar tags be made synonyms of [iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/iphone)? I can see why [ipad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ipad) should be kept separate, as there are some implementation differences in the firmware, but for the iPod and the iPhone, the only major difference I can see is the presence/absence of telephony.

I suggested them as synonyms a few days ago, but now I'm questioning myself as to whether or not they are suitable.

Comment: That one _major_ difference definitely warrants a separate tag.

Comment: I disagree. Questions relating to telephony are likely to include an extra tag anyway

Comment: There are plenty of differences: GPS, Cellular, Camera capabilities... A user asking about getting positioning services to work on a iPod will only get iPhone answers...

Answer (score 1):

iPhones and iPod Touches are similar but not the same and should not be synonyms.

As Cerbrus pointed out, they do not have the same capabilities: [iOS Device Compatibility](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeviceInformation/Reference/iOSDeviceCompatibility/DeviceCompatibilityMatrix/DeviceCompatibilityMatrix.html)