# Is it possible to get a featured tag badge?

Tags: discussion, support, meta, tag-badges

I posted an answer in a question that had the [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) tag recently that got a fair amount of upvotes, that got me wondering if you could possibly get the [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) tag badge. But then I noticed that after some time the tag seems to disappear from the question. So, is it correct that it is impossible to get a [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) tag badge?

Comment: Seems legit.  Tag badges are the only badge that disappears if your score in the tag drops lower, and since [meta-tag:featured] is removed, it makes sense that you'd never be able to get the minimum 20 questions in the tag to qualify for bronze.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

A tag has to appear on at least 100 questions before it's eligible for tag badges, so no, because that would never happen unless we were massively misusing the tag.

Answer (score 4):

Tag badges are the only ones that are recalculated.  This means that [you can gain and lose them](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/301017/4320665) if the questions get retagged or your answers' scores change.  It would technically be possible to have 100 answer score on 20 questions with the [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) tag.  Good luck finding 20 questions with that tag though.  Also, you'd lose the badge as soon as enough of the questions were had the tag removed.

So yes, it's technically possible but would never happen in practice.  And it would be even harder to keep.

Comment: Just to clarify, you could technically meet the score / number of answers requirements on a single question by posting 20 answers. The tag badges don't specify the answers have to be on different questions.

Comment: @animuson ah thanks.  Of course at that point the problem is probably going to be the score for the answers.  But since most of this answer is technicalities anyway that's not a big concern.