# Does editing an answered question's tags add reputation for this tag retroactively?

Tags: support, tags, edits, reputation, tag-badges

Let's say I got +15 reputation for answering a question tagged as C# only. So now I earned +15 reputation to my C# tag badge.

Now let's say this question also involved Javascript.

Does editing this question, after it was resolved, and adding the Javascript tag, adds +15 reputation to my Javascript tag badge retroactively?

---

**EDIT**:

While reviewing Edits, I've seen alot of irrelevant tag edits, and this question popped to my mind. I think there's a trend of abusing this feature.

Comment: This is somewhat said in the answer, but it should be stressed out as you seem to  have a slight misunderstanding: accepted answers do not count *at all* towards badge score. Only net score on an answer does. The score on an answer you gave, will be added, or removed, to and from the tags on the question, accordingly to the edits.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Yes, adding a tag to a question will retroactively change your score in that tag.  Also, if the tag is removed then it will also change your score in that tag.

Do note though that the rep you get from getting an accepted answer doesn't count towards your answer score.  Your tag score is your net up votes on answers to questions with that tag.

Comment: This sometimes leads to adding irrelevant tags in order to boost answer score

Comment: Is this also true for the user who added the tag if they had an answer on this question?

Comment: "_Do note though that accepted answers don't count towards answer score_" Do you mean that upvotes on answers that are accepted don't count, or that it doesn't make any difference for the score if the answer is accepted or not?

Comment: @DonaldDuck He means that the reputation gain from accepted answers does not count towards the tag badge, but only the net score (not rep as OP implied) of your answers in that tag.

Comment: @EpicKip So if I understand correctly, upvotes on accepted answers do count, but not the +15 reputation earned from the answer being accepted?

Comment: @DonaldDuck You got it now ;) rep isn't counted only net score (so you need +100 total answer score assuming you have no downvoted answers)

Comment: @user7294900 Precisely. That's why I asked this question: While reviewing Edits, I've seen alot of irrelevant tags, and this question popped to my mind.

Comment: @Kaiido if so, then that should be police-able by other users. If an answerer edits the question to add irrelevant tags, revert the edit :)

Comment: @RobertColumbia but what if the edit was correct ? We're not all here for the game. And my question was a real question, I think I did heard something like that some times ago, but I may be completely wrong.

Comment: @Kaiido , then just edit remove the irrelevant tag and leave the rest of the edit. The problem of answerers adding gratuitous tags to the questions that they answered is self-correcting.

Comment: It could be noted (and maybe added to this answer) that badges, once gained, will *not* be removed even if your score in a particular badge goes under the threshold.

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier Tag badges are special.  You will lose them if your score no longer qualifies: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/301017/do-you-lose-a-gold-tag-badge-if-questions-are-retagged

Comment: As a follow up, do the votes you get from answers and questions add up even after you've hit your daily limit?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Everything I have seen says yes.  I know for a fact it works that way on meta

Comment: @NathanOliver Does bounty add reputation to the tag? Say I gained `100` reps from a tag `abc`, will that increase my tab rep by `10`?

Comment: @CopsOnRoad No.  Score in a tag is only `(total_number_of_up_votes - total_number_of_down_votes) * 10`