# Is it acceptable to retroactively bulk add a new tag to old questions?

Tags: discussion, tags, bulk-tagging

**The scenario:**
I work on a software product that has been around for several years and has the [websphere-liberty] tag for questions related to it.  Recently we open sourced a subset of this product under the name OpenLiberty, with a corresponding [open-liberty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/open-liberty) tag.  So effectively all of the [open-liberty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/open-liberty) questions are a subset of the [websphere-liberty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/websphere-liberty) questions.

**What the OpenLiberty community wants to do:**
We would like to manually work through all of the past [websphere-liberty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/websphere-liberty) questions and add the tag [open-liberty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/open-liberty) to questions that also apply to the subset of WebSphere Liberty that became OpenLiberty.

I wanted to check with the meta community before doing this, because it could be seen as a rep grab (since [retroactively adding tags to questions also awards tag points](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/355169/does-editing-an-answered-questions-tags-add-reputation-for-this-tag-retroactive)), but that is not our goal.  The main goal is to preserve the archive of useful questions that the existing community has built up and carry them into the open source community.

Comment: "since retroactively adding tags to questions also awards rep" No, it doesn't.  It changes your score in that tag.  That's different than your reputation.  The post you link to says as much.

Comment: Minor nitpick: retagging only changes the *score* in that tag, not your reputation.

Comment: thanks for clarifying.  That makes me think this retagging effort will be more acceptable now.  Can't think of any reasons why it wouldn't be acceptable at this point

Comment: Make sure that only users with the edit privilege participate in the retaging.

Comment: @AndyGuibert The changes to the score is something most people tend to not care about.  The real problem is the mass editing of questions becomes very disruptive to the question feeds.  Suddenly it becomes impossible to see what questions are actually having *meaningful* changes to the relevant tags as the feed is just flooded with some retag effort.  (It also causes a *lot* more problems when done by users without edit privileges, so as BDL mentioned, you *really* need to be sure anyone involved in something like this has edit privileges).

Comment: that's a good point about edit privs.  We'll be sure to only have users with edit privs do the retagging to avoid flooding the review queue.

Comment: You can also spread out the edits as to not flood the homepage with edited questions as well.

Comment: Also be sure that when you edit the tags, you also clean up any grammar, punctuation, spelling, etc that needs cleaned on the question! Don't just retag, fix any other issues!

Comment: Who exactly benefits from this disruptive action?

Comment: @Gimby the benefit is that users of the new product (OpenLiberty) can search for questions and have that include the 5 year history of useful questions/answers that have accumulated.

Comment: @BDL I'm just curious: why only users with the edit privilege?

Comment: @gparyani because otherwise the edits all need to be reviewed, which could flood the edit review queue.

Comment: In theory yes, in practice, no.

Answer (score 6):

Is there a meaningful difference between the questions that would be tagged with [websphere-liberty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/websphere-liberty) and [open-liberty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/open-liberty)? If, as I suspect, one of the two products is simply a subset of the other, it would probably be more appropriate for the two tags to be configured as synonyms. That way, questions which pertain to both products can be answered more effectively.