# Tag edit reversal does not revert awarded badge

Tags: discussion, bug

I had 398 score in the C tag and 188 score in the C++ tag. I answered *[What does `int* p=+s;` do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50598177/what-does-int-p-s-do)* with the C++ tag and got six upvotes. I suddenly got notified that I have received the silver badge in the C tag which surprised me as I didn't receive any upvote in C tag recently.

Then I noticed that this question was edited to add the C tag instead of the C++ tag which later was reverted by the OP. Yes, the question can be a valid C question too, but the OP clearly had C++ in mind and the reversal of the tag edit is okay.

However, now I have 194 upvotes in C++ tag and 404 upvotes in C tag, and I still have the silver badge.

Shouldn't my score in C go back to 398 and the awarded badge be reverted?

Comment: I believe there's a daily script that fixes those things, I vaguely recall testing that a while back. See if it's changed by tomorrow. Found a reference here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269040/when-is-tag-score-calculated

Comment: Yes, the script that awards the badges once per day also handles revoking them at the same time.

Comment: @ivarni back then the badge was probably awarded later, but since now the badge gets awarded immediately I'm not sure whether that will fix it. Anyway, I will see it tomorrow.

Comment: @BoltClock does it still run daily at some fixed time? Then how the badge was awarded immediately after tag edit?

Comment: You probably qualified sooner, and the upvote coming at the same time as the badge notification was a coincidence.

Comment: Yes, the awarded badge got reverted by the daily script.